# Questions about the fork() function in UNIX

Tags: unix, process, operating-system, fork

I’m writing a program that simulates an unix-based operating system for an assignment and I have some questions.

1) I read that a newly created process in UNIX that is not yet ready for execution is in the „created” state, and a proces that is waiting to be assigned to a processor is in the „ready” state. 
What exacly happens so a „created” process can become „ready’? 
Does it change it’s state from „created’ to „ready” while being created in the fork() function?

2) When the fork() function finish to create the process, it puts the process
in the Job queue, then a long-term scheduler selects which process to put in the Ready queue. Is this correct? Because somewhere else I read that it puts the process directly in the Ready queue, and I’m confused.
How does the long-term scheduler works? Which criteria it uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for FreeBSD, although Linux isn't horribly different.

The `created` state marks that a new process is still being built.  Among the first things the `fork` system call does is allocate a slot in the process table, increment the max process counter, and assign a new process ID. The rest of the system will then know about this while the `fork` system call does other necessary tasks to finalize process creation (copy file descriptors from the parent, initialize scheduler structures, attach the process to its parent, etc).  After this longer work is done, the process is moved to the `ready` state.

I believe that neither FreeBSD nor Linux have formal long-term or admission schedulers.  Once ready, Linux attempts to put the child in front of the parent in priority, FreeBSD just allows normal scheduling to take place.

See `do_fork()` in http://svn.freebsd.org/base/release/10.1.0/sys/kern/kern_fork.c
and check out http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch03lev1sec2